# Fit a mixture of von Mises distributions in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a set of angular data that I'd like to fit a mixture of two von Mises distributions to.  As shown below, the data are clustered at about 0 and ±π, so having a periodic boundary is required for this case.  [image: Distribution of data]

I have tried using the movMF package to fit a distribution to these data but it seems that it is normalizing each row, and since this is a set of 1D data, the result is a vector of ±1.  How are others fitting a mixture of distributions like this in R?

Comment: Can you explain what you've been trying?  For example, if you write a "two von Mises dist" generalized function and run `nls` with your data and that function, what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies with using a vector of angles as the input to the movMF function.  Instead, the angles must be converted to points on the unit circle

```
pts_on_unit_circle <- cbind(cos(angle_in_degrees * pi / 180), 
                            sin(angle_in_degrees * pi / 180))
d <- movMF(pts_on_unit_circle, number_of_mixed_vM_fxns)
mu <- atan2(d$theta[,2], d$theta[,1])
kappa <- sqrt(rowSums(d$theta^2))
```

Source: Contacted Kurt Hornik, the author of the movMF package.

Comment: Can I use movMF in Python to fit mixture of von Mises distributions? The doc says its about von Mises - Fisher distribution.

Comment: @cqcn1991 the von Mises distribution is a special case of the von Mises-Fisher distribution.