# Python: How to fit a mixture of a von Mises Distribution?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have a angular distribution, and I want to fit a mixture of von Mises distribution to that

[image]

How can I do that?

I find an implementation in R, [Fit a mixture of von Mises distributions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788748/fit-a-mixture-of-von-mises-distributions-in-r)

I also find it is possible to fit a single von Mises distributio in Python, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.vonmises.html

I think maybe I can try to how to fit a mixture distribution, given I have the function already defined in `scipy`?

---

Finally, I solved this problem using `rpy2`. Specifcally, I cleaned data using Python, and traind the VMM using the R packages (so instll R and related packges is required).

Comment: How many von Mises distributions are you wanting to sum?  Is it a fixed number?

Comment: @DavisHerring within 10

Comment: Well, you’ll almost always get a better fit (and always at least as good) with more basis functions, so “within 10” just means 10.

Comment: @DavisHerring goodness-of-fit is not the only consideration. I also take cross validation effect into account. So in my study, the actual range is between 3-6. With more components, the result only gets slightly better.

Comment: Related: Mixture models in scipy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759577/creating-a-mixture-of-probability-distributions-for-sampling

Answer (score 5):

I implemented an algorithm to solve a similar problem, see

https://framagit.org/fraschelle/mixture-of-von-mises-distributions

for full details.

Starting from a random sample (a 1D `numpy.array`), it applies an [expectation-maximization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) to classify the data according to the von-Mises distribution.

The algorithm allows for any superposition of von-Mises distributions (although the [mathematics associated with the algorithm](https://framagit.org/fraschelle/mixture-of-von-mises-distributions/blob/master/von_Mises_superposition.pdf) (link to pdf) only describes a superposition of two distributions, it is quite easy to generalise), and it is as fast as I could do. It relies only on Numpy and the `iv` function of `scipy.special`, to call the modified Bessel function.

The mixture_mises_pdfit returns the weight of each distribution, and the $\mu$ and $\kappa$ parameters, see e.g. the [Wikipedia page on von Mises distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution).

It would be nice to add a real classification outcome of the code, in order to allow classification of periodic data. Eventually, an extension to Scikit-learn should be feasible as well, though it requires more time to implement.

Comment: Links are not working. It would be really nice if you make a GitHub repository for your work :)

Comment: @Yashas Sorry, I changed my account name at framagit. The link is now working. Tell me if it does not, and thank you for pointing this mistake of mine.

Comment: thank you so much for this. I plan to write a paper using part of your solution, I'd like to know how I can properly cite it.

Comment: @FraSchelle, your package cannot be installed through the PyPi channel using pip install

Comment: @FengHu Indeed, and so what ? Better to make an extension of sk-learn I guess. I you have time, go :-)