# Creating a mixture of probability distributions for sampling

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability-density

Is there a general way to join SciPy (or NumPy) probability distributions to create a mixture probability distribution which can then be sampled from?

I have such a distribution for display using something like:

```
mixture_gaussian = (norm.pdf(x_axis, -3, 1) + norm.pdf(x_axis, 3, 1)) / 2
```

which if then plotted looks like:

[image: double gaussian]

However, I can't sample from this generated model, as it's just a list of points which will plot as the curve.

Note, this specific distribution is just a simple example. I'd like to be able to generate several kinds of distributions (including "sub"-distributions which are not just normal distributions). Ideally, I would hope there would be someway for the function to be automatically normalized (i.e. not having to do the `/ 2` explicitly as in the code above.

Does SciPy/NumPy provide some way of easily accomplishing this?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42342639/1191087) provides a way that such a sampling from a multiple distributions could be done, but it certainly requires a bit of handcrafting for a given mixture distribution, especially when wanting to weight different "sub"-distributions differently. This is usable, but I would hope for method that's a bit cleaner and straight forward if possible. Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42563049/7207392) may help you get started.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sampling from a mixture of distributions (where PDFs are added with some coefficients c_1, c_2, ... c_n) is equivalent to sampling each independently, and then, for each index, picking the value from k-th sample, with probability c_k.

The latter, mixing, step can be efficiently done with `numpy.random.choice`. Here is an example where three distributions are mixed. The distributions are listed in `distributions`, and their coefficients in `coefficients`.  There is a fat normal distribution, a uniform distribution, and a narrow normal distribution, with coefficients 0.5, 0.2, 0.3.  The mixing happens at `data[np.arange(sample_size), random_idx]` after `random_idx` are generated according to given coefficients.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

distributions = [
    {"type": np.random.normal, "kwargs": {"loc": -3, "scale": 2}},
    {"type": np.random.uniform, "kwargs": {"low": 4, "high": 6}},
    {"type": np.random.normal, "kwargs": {"loc": 2, "scale": 1}},
]
coefficients = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.3])
coefficients /= coefficients.sum()      # in case these did not add up to 1
sample_size = 100000

num_distr = len(distributions)
data = np.zeros((sample_size, num_distr))
for idx, distr in enumerate(distributions):
    data[:, idx] = distr["type"](size=(sample_size,), **distr["kwargs"])
random_idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(num_distr), size=(sample_size,), p=coefficients)
sample = data[np.arange(sample_size), random_idx]
plt.hist(sample, bins=100, density=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 12):

Following @PaulPanzer's pointer in the comments, I created the following subclass for easily creating mixture models from the SciPy distributions. Note, the `pdf` is not required for my question, but it was nice for me to have.

```
class MixtureModel(rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self, submodels, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.submodels = submodels

    def _pdf(self, x):
        pdf = self.submodels[0].pdf(x)
        for submodel in self.submodels[1:]:
            pdf += submodel.pdf(x)
        pdf /= len(self.submodels)
        return pdf

    def rvs(self, size):
        submodel_choices = np.random.randint(len(self.submodels), size=size)
        submodel_samples = [submodel.rvs(size=size) for submodel in self.submodels]
        rvs = np.choose(submodel_choices, submodel_samples)
        return rvs

mixture_gaussian_model = MixtureModel([norm(-3, 1), norm(3, 1)])
x_axis = np.arange(-6, 6, 0.001)
mixture_pdf = mixture_gaussian_model.pdf(x_axis)
mixture_rvs = mixture_gaussian_model.rvs(10)
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to "weight different "sub"-distributions differently"; here they all get the same weight.

Comment: @CrazyIvan, that's correct. I will eventually want them to be able to be weighted differently. For the moment what I wrote is sufficient, but eventually I will have to change my random selections (and the scaling of the `pdf`) to something closer to what you did in your answer.

Comment: @Jenny Shoars, I’m having a similar problem to yours. However, I’d be interested in weighting the input sub-distributions differently. Can you give me a hint how this could be implemented (especially for_pdf)? Btw, I had to replace the following line in your code `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` with `super(MixtureModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` in order to avoid an error message.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to other commenters on Jenny Shoars answer, I needed the weights to be uneven and also wanted to be able to look at more than the pdf.

I augmented her approach and extended the class so you can specify the weights, and also provide `cdf` and `sf` in addition `pdf` and `rvs`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

class MixtureModel(stats.rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self, submodels, *args, weights = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.submodels = submodels
        if weights is None:
            weights = [1 for _ in submodels]
        if len(weights) != len(submodels):
            raise(ValueError(f'There are {len(submodels)} submodels and {len(weights)} weights, but they must be equal.'))
        self.weights = [w / sum(weights) for w in weights]
        
    def _pdf(self, x):
        pdf = self.submodels[0].pdf(x) * self.weights[0]
        for submodel, weight in zip(self.submodels[1:], self.weights[1:]):
            pdf += submodel.pdf(x)  * weight
        return pdf
            
    def _sf(self, x):
        sf = self.submodels[0].sf(x) * self.weights[0]
        for submodel, weight in zip(self.submodels[1:], self.weights[1:]):
            sf += submodel.sf(x)  * weight
        return sf

    def _cdf(self, x):
        cdf = self.submodels[0].cdf(x) * self.weights[0]
        for submodel, weight in zip(self.submodels[1:], self.weights[1:]):
            cdf += submodel.cdf(x)  * weight
        return cdf

        

    def rvs(self, size):
        submodel_choices = np.random.choice(len(self.submodels), size=size, p = self.weights)
        submodel_samples = [submodel.rvs(size=size) for submodel in self.submodels]
        rvs = np.choose(submodel_choices, submodel_samples)
        return rvs

mixture_model = MixtureModel([stats.norm(-3, 1), 
                              stats.norm(3, 1), 
                              stats.uniform(loc=3, scale = 2)],
                             weights = [0.3, 0.5, 0.2])
```

Giving

```
x_axis = np.arange(-6, 6, 0.001)
plt.plot(x_axis, mixture_model.sf(x_axis), label = 'SF')
plt.plot(x_axis, mixture_model.cdf(x_axis), label = 'CDF')
plt.plot(x_axis, mixture_model.pdf(x_axis), label = 'PDF')

plt.hist(mixture_model.rvs(10**5), bins = 50, density = True, label = 'Sampled')
plt.legend()
```

[image: plots]

Answer (score 0):

The code below stores a 1000 samples from *N(0,1)* and 500 samples from *N(7,2)* in an array that can then be sampled from.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

d = np.concatenate((stats.norm.rvs(0.0, 1.0, 1000), stats.norm.rvs(7.0, 2.0, 500)))
np.random.choice(d, 3)  # sample 3 observations
```

Mixture components other than the Normal can be used (e.g., `stats.poisson`) and there can be arbitrary number of those.